# Sizing an <ul> in a table cell

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm building an HTML view consisting of a `<table>`, with each cell containing only a single `<ul>` element, with a variable number of `<li>`. For readability reasons, my rows have a `min-width: 100px;`, but expand based on the contents of the `<ul>`. But in the other cells (which a lower number of `<li>`). I want my `<ul>` to use 100% of the cell's height. At the moment, they keep the 100px height and are verticaly centered.

My view can be summed up to that :

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <ul>...</ul>
        </td>
        <td>
            <ul>...</ul>
        </td>
        <td>
            <ul>...</ul>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <ul>...</ul>
        </td>
        <td>
            <ul>...</ul>
        </td>
        <td>
            <ul>...</ul>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

My reason for this, is that each `<li>` can be dragged & dropped between every `<ul>`, but the fact they are not resizing make dropping on an empty list kind of hazardous, because you don't "see" them, and have to guess where they are. It would be a lot easier if they were using the full cell dimensions.

I have made a lot of tries using developer tools, but could not find the right combination of CSS and Javascript.

Technicals prerequisites :

- Javascript DOM manipulation is OK, I already do it to resize my table. I use ExtJS, but I'm OK with porting jQuery or pure JS code.
- Compatibility with IE8 is a must (75% of final users are on IE. Gotta love the corporate world...)

Thanks for any advice !

EDIT : Here's a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Squ36/P5h8d/) that represents my code as closely as possible (NDA prevents me from sharing the original code)

Comment: can you set up a jsfiddle with what you have already?

Comment: Just edited my post !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For `height: 100%` to work as expected the container must have its `height` set. I have a solution below that uses JavaScript to set the height of all the ul's, it can be used as a function that runs every time it changes if needed:

```
function fixDimensions() {
    var table = document.getElementById('table');
    var trs = table.getElementsByTagName('tr');
    for(var i = 0; i < trs.length; i++){
        var tds = trs[i].getElementsByTagName('td');
        for(var g = 0; g < tds.length; g++){
            var ul = tds[g].getElementsByTagName('ul')[0];
            ul.style.height = (tds[g].clientHeight - 12) + 'px';
        }
    }
}
```

The `- 12` on the height is for the padding and border. [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/P5h8d/1/).

Comment: I thought about using JS to resize them, but I wanted to keep it as a last resort, since the rendering alone fires up the "Script is taking too long" popup on IE8. I'll wait a couple of days, and if noone offers a pure CSS solution, I'll go that way

Comment: Would setting the target for the drop as the `<td>` that would then append it to the `<ul>` be any better option? Still uses JS though.

Comment: It doesn't really matter which of the `td` or `ul` is the drop target, but it's simpler if it's the `ul`, since it saves me a DOM query to find it

Comment: It would probably be better than my solution. I have no experience with ExtJS though.

Comment: ExtJS is mostly irrelevant here. I only mentionned it for folks who might know about it and then offer a custom solution, but it offers DOM manipulation like jQuery and such, as well as rich interface building. My problem here is mostly about HTML and CSS, although I can fix it with JS if nothing turns up

Comment: If you do choose this option setting the `height` of the `<td>` rather than the `<ul>` would be more effective speed-wise.

Comment: you may want to test this , CSS cures the lack of ul height : http://jsfiddle.net/P5h8d/3/ my last contribution :)

Answer (score 1):

You could use td themselves to draw the borders : http://jsfiddle.net/P5h8d/2/

```
table {
    width: 100%;
    background:black;
    border-spacing:1px;
}

tr {
    min-height: 50px;
    width: 100%;
}

tbody th, tbody td {
    border: 3px dotted red;
}
 th, td {
    width: 20%;
    background:white;
}
```

---

You might not need a table if:

---

1. you use `display:table` instead `<table>` to turn `<ul>` visually into a cell.

**[DEMO](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/qHnah/)**

---

```
<section>
      <div>
        <ul>
          <li> itelm</li>...
        </ul>
        <ul>
          <li> itelm</li>...
        </ul>
        <ul>
          <li> itelm</li>...
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div>
        <ul>
          <li> itelm</li>...
        </ul>
        <ul>
          <li> itelm</li>...
        </ul>
        <ul>
          <li> itelm</li>...
        </ul>
      </div>
    </section>
```

CSS

```
section {
  display:table;
  border-spacing:5px;
}
section > div {
  display:table-row;
}
section>div>ul {
  display:table-cell;
  background:red;
  min-width:100px;
}
```

---

1. you use display:flex;

**[DEMO](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/klbem/)**

---

basic CSS used :

```
tr {
  display:flex;/* reset display:defaut*/
}
td {background:gray;
display:flex;/* here again display reset */
flex-direction:column;/* make sure we draw content from top to bottom */
  margin:2px;
}
ul {
  padding:0;
  margin:5px;;
  min-width:100px;
  background:red;
  flex:1;/* fills or shares whole height of its flex box*/
}
```

Comment: I did not know about the "flex" display modes, but after a quick Googling it sounds amazing. But it's only available for IE starting at v10 (and even then it's only partial support) and like I said in my OP I need to maintain IE8 compatibility

Comment: for IE8 , drop the table , set uls in a container set as display:table or table-row, and use them as cells : display:table-cell. IE8 will get it

Comment: I thought about that, but it's really easier to traverse a table's DOM tree than a pack of divs. And it's easier to build.
Plus, my template is already 100% working with all the functionalities, it's the only "bug" left. I'm really not feeling like tearing the whole thing down to rebuild it from scratch

Comment: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/qHnah/ this is the idea , if you generate this from a php routine, you do not have much to do to update, else any editor has the searc and replace function :)

Comment: I personally like the idea, but I don't think my boss will like me spending time rebuilding all the template for a "cosmetic" improvement.

Comment: well it's up to him , he has the cosmetic or no fall back for older browsers , i would keep te table + flex and use bg of td for 'ul' and leave ul bg translucide. and eventually reset vertical-align on tds

Comment: The cosmetic part is not the borders, it's the size of the `ul` elements, because they are drop targets for the `li`

Comment: okay i seee :), you just need to tune the drop script to get td to accept drop too & move li to ul if it not in

Answer (score 0):

*Not to pollute my first answer, **added here the drag and drop js***

No matter the height of the `ul` , `li` drops in !

---

here is a CSS way to extend area around an element to increase area where it can catch  mouse events.
IE8 understands `:before`/`:after` , so we use them. and set them in absolute position on top and bottom of your `ul`.

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/P5h8d/3/)**

---

the CSS used:

```
td {overflow:hidden;/*keep ul:pseudos inside */}
ul {
    position:relative;
}
ul:before,
ul:after {
    content:'';
    position:absolute;
    height:200px;/* whatever you need or think it is safe */
    left:0;
    width:100%;
}
ul:before {
    bottom:100%;
}
ul:after {
    top:100%;

}
```

added to the demo basic HTML5 drag and drop (attributes and js) since it was missing from your fiddle.

```
function allowDrop(ev){ev.preventDefault();}
function drag(ev){ev.dataTransfer.setData("Text",ev.target.id);}
function drop(ev){ev.preventDefault();
var data=ev.dataTransfer.getData("Text");
ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));}
```